# MultipeerConnectivity issue with Podspec

Tags: cocoapods, multipeer-connectivity

I've been trying to add a library with MultiPeerConnectivity framework but when I check podspec is ok I get the following issue:

`'MultipeerConnectivity/MultipeerConnectivity.h' file not found`

And the podspec

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
  s.name         = 'MagicMP'
  s.license      = 'MIT'
  s.platform = :ios, '7.0'
  s.version      = '1.0.3'                                                                  # 1
  s.summary      = 'MultiPeer framework done better' # 2
  s.author       = { 'Pedro Piñera' => 'pepibumur@gmail.com' }                            # 3
  s.homepage     = "https://github.com/pepibumur/PPiShowtime-Google-iOS-Library"
  s.source       = { :git => 'https://github.com/pepibumur/MagicMP.git' , :tag => '1.0.3'}      # 4
  s.ios.deployment_target = '7.0'
  s.source_files = 'MagicMP/*'
  s.requires_arc = true
  s.frameworks = 'MultipeerConnectivity'
end
```

Comment: Not being able to find the Apple framework sounds like an SDK issue. Are you linking with the iOS 7 SDK?

Comment: @KeithSmiley linking exactly in what part?

Comment: MultipeerConnectivity is a header in its own framework that only exists in iOS 7. So if your code cannot find that header in that framework there may be an issue with the SDK it's looking in.

Comment: And in where should I specify it because compiling directly works right :S @KeithSmiley

Comment: Sorry I forgot tagging @KeithSmiley on the comment